# Can others on "Home" or "Work" networks access my Windows 7 computer?

Tags: windows-7, networking

I am having Windows 7 Home Basic. If I am using **Home** or **Work** network, can others connect to my PC even if Remote Assistance is disabled ?

By *connect* I mean others being able to do any of the following:

1. Copying files from my PC
2. Copying files to my PC
3. Seeing or reading files residing on my computer

By *others* I mean other people(computers) on same network.

Comment: Do you know what "remote assistance" means?

Comment: @KimJong-Un yeah, some other person(from other computer) being able to browse my my folders/files

Comment: Wrong! http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/what-is-windows-remote-assistance

Comment: @Austin''Danger''Powers There's no need to be condescending. We were all at a similar state of knowledge at one point or another.

Answer (score 0):

Of course other computers on the network can connect to your computer. Your Windows 7 computer supports network sharing, so others can share files to you and you can share files to others.

Can they connect without your permission? Generally no, however that is not a question we can really answer here, since in order to give you an accurate answer, we'd need to see the exact configuration of your system. If you'd like to make sure your system is secure, you should read up on how Windows handles network authentication and sharing, and look up guides on how to lock down your system and keep it secure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default settings with Home or Work networks, then no. Unless you enable file and printer sharing as well as public folder sharing manually, they are disabled by default. They can discover your computer, but can't do anything with your files.